# How to determine which checkbox is checked?

Tags: php, jquery, html, checkbox

I have an HTML table of four columns: `studentID`, `first_name`, `last_name` and 5 checkboxes with grades. How can I determine in PHP (or maybe using JQuery?) which check box(grade) was checked for each `studentID`?

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <?php print $stud_row['student_id']; ?>
    </td>
    <td>
        <?php print $stud_row['first_name']; ?>
    </td>
    <td>
        <?php print $stud_row['last_name']; ?>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="id" value="a"> A 
        <input type="checkbox" name="id" value="b"> B 
        <input type="checkbox" name="id" value="c"> C 
        <input type="checkbox" name="id" value="d"> D 
        <input type="checkbox" name="id" value="f"> F
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Are the checkboxes like an array? `grades[]`

Comment: <tr>                                                                  <td><?php print $stud_row['student_id']; ?></td>                    <td><?php print $stud_row['first_name']; ?></td>                          <td><?php print $stud_row['last_name']; ?></td>                     <td><input type = "checkbox" name = "id" value = "a"> A              <input type = "checkbox" name = "id" value="b"> B 
<input type = "checkbox" name = "id" value="c"> C
<input type = "checkbox" name = "id" value="d"> D 
<input type = "checkbox" name = "id" value="f"> F </td></tr>

Comment: Please show what `$stud_row` looks like.

Comment: Thank you for responding. $stud_row consists of 'student_id','last_name','first_name'.

Comment: You will need to wrap your html around <form> tags, would you like help with this?

Comment: Thank you, I have <form> tags. I just don't know how to determine which checbox is checked in each row. I tried to find how to have value attribute for each row and then check which is checked, but didn't find anything.

Comment: Consider giving the boxes names like "id[a]" and "id[b]", etc. Btw, didn't you mean to use radio buttons?

Comment: Thank you, when I use radio buttons then in the next row the previous gets unselected. I have a number of students, each have to be assigned a grade which I'm trying to accomplish in a for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a fully functional example on how to see which grade is selected using jQuery:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
    $('.grade').on('change',function(){
        if($(this).is(':checked')){
            $('#grades').append($(this).val());
        }else{
            $('#grades').html($('#grades').html().replace($(this).val(),''));
        }
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input class="grade" type="checkbox" name="a" value="a"> A <br>
<input class="grade" type="checkbox" name="b" value="b"> B <br>
<input class="grade" type="checkbox" name="c" value="c"> C <br>
<input class="grade" type="checkbox" name="d" value="d"> D <br>
<input class="grade" type="checkbox" name="f" value="f"> F <br>
<div id="grades"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Then if you need to see it on the server just use ajax or a form to pass it back.

Comment: Thank you, dkroy. I don't really know ajax yet, I'm not sure where would you call this function? I'm using a <form> and passing grades to another file.